# Adding a four digit counter to the paypal button payment reference

Tags: html, button, logging, paypal, counter

I am really sorry but I am not a developer and have been directed to this site by Paypal. 
I am trying to add a four digit counter the payment side of the paypal Button reference. So I have a paypal button that has a reference of Bowl and I set a quantity of 2000. each purchase has a unique payment number but I want the reference to have a four digit count as well, so Bowl - 0001 then next purchase Bowl - 0002 and so on up to the last one purchased Bowl - 2000. Is this possible please. Sorry if its obvious.

Cooperman

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. We're happy to debug,fix or improve your code but were not a code-writing service tho.

Comment: I am sorry but as I said I am not a developer and I dont write code. Not sure why I was directed here by the operative at paypal today then. Sorry. Steve.